# Overlay a label on an axwindowsmediaplayer control while in fullscreen mode?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

As the title suggests, I'd like to overlay a label on an axwindowsmediaplayer control while in fullscreen mode.

Has anyone any idea how to do it?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: dock the `axWindowsMediaPlayer` in a form with `FormBorderStyle = None` then maximize that form and it should keep the label on-top, as for using the build-in full-screen Boolean in the control, there is no easy way to use that and keep a label on-top of it as far as i know, if you want that then you can ether draw it manually with some Win API or overlay a transparent form with the label(both have there downsides)

Answer (score 0):

I did my by...

1. Creating 2 forms.1 with the media player set to what ever size needed
2. The second form with...

   ```
   formborderstyle = none
   form2.left = form1.left + form1.mediaplayer.left 
   form2.top = form1.top +  form1.mediaplayer.top
   ```
3. Lower the opacity to 70 or if you want it in code..

   ```
   form2.opacity=0.7
   ```
4. Put your text or anything in the second form .

The final effect is a cool shade like effect with text in it with media playing in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the [windowlessVideo property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It mentions this exact use case in the documentation.

> By default, an embedded Windows Media Player control renders video in its own window within the client area. When windowlessVideo is set to true, the Windows Media Player object renders video directly in the client area, so you can apply special effects or layer the video with text.