# axwindowsmediaplayer overlay fullscreen with a form

Tags: c#, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have a windows forms application with multiple forms. The main form contains an instance of an axwindowsmediaplayer, and it also has an instance of a subtitle form. This subtitle form only contains a label.

What happens now is if I set my player to fullscreen and then show the subtitle form with `topmost = true`, the player leaves fullscreen mode. If I first show the subtitle form and then set the player to fullscreen the subtitle form dissapears

I looked at the answers given at [Overlay a label on an axwindowsmediaplayer control while in fullscreen mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610979/overlay-a-label-on-an-axwindowsmediaplayer-control-while-in-fullscreen-mode) but they didn't seem to work for me